# C#.Net VS 2013 writes to folder but then cannot find the same folder to read from

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a C# MVC 5 web app for internal users. The app generates XML reports that are sent out to clients. As a convenience to our internal users, we also want these reports available to them for download.

Writing the report and saving it to a folder works without issue. However, when I try to read from the same folder, it can't be found.

So I save the file using the Save() method of the XmlDocument class. The file gets saved perfectly; I am able to open it up directly in a text editor.

However, when I try to retrieve the file from code, using Response.WriteFile(), I get an IO exception.

Here is the offending code (it's in a controller class):

```
public void DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    var mappedPath = Server.MapPath("/SiteRoot/Downloads/" + fileName);
    Response.WriteFile(mappedPath);
    Response.End();
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\jrobson\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ProjectName\SiteRoot\Downloads\'.
```

When I copy the path from the above error message and paste it into Windows explorer, it works fine. It navigates right to the folder.

So what is going on? The permissions are obviously there. The folder exists. Why can the app find the folder to write to, but not to read from?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
var mappedPath = Server.MapPath("/SiteRoot/Downloads/" + fileName);
```

this

```
var mappedPath = Server.MapPath("~/SiteRoot/Downloads/" + fileName);
```

Comment: MateusBello - thanks for your response. I tried the "~" syntax and it makes no difference. The error is exactly the same. As I mentioned in my original post, Server.MapPath is constructing the correct physical path; I can paste it into Windows Explorer and it works perfectly. So the problem does not appear to be in the way the path is formed.

Comment: Sorry for that. In this case, you can try another folder like c:\test in the case it is a permission issue. I would also try running VS with administrator privileges.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your efforts. I've tried different folders, and always run VS as admin.

Comment: Well, the last thing I can think of is to load the xml to a string variable `string xmlString =  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);`  and use `Response.Write(xmlString);`

Comment: Thanks again, but ReadAllText throws the same error that WriteFile throws. Could not find a part of the path.

Comment: Is the fileName variable null or empty by any chance? or maybe it contains invalid characters or double '//'?

Comment: The filename is not empty, null, or otherwise invalid. It prints out correctly in the error message. In the end, I abandoned this altogether, and just use JavaScript to navigate the browser to the file in question. It's not what we wanted - it required opening another browser window - but it gets the job done, and we couldn't afford to spend more time fighting this issue.